# Delphi - Invalid typecast of WParam and LParam in 64-bit

Tags: delphi

I have the following code that compiles fine in 32-bit, but gives invalid typecast error in 64-bit. The procedure is processing the windows messages:

```
procedure TCustomForm.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
 var
  Point: TPoint;
  Rect: TRect;
begin
 with Message do
   case Msg of
      WM_ERASEBKGND:
        Result := 0;
      WM_GETMINMAXINFO:
        with PMinMaxInfo(lParam)^ do
        begin
          QueryTrackSize(PTrackSize(@ptMinTrackSize)^);
          Result := 0;
        end;
      WM_NCHITTEST:
        begin
          Point.x := SmallInt(LongRec(LParam).Lo); // error
          Point.y := SmallInt(LongRec(LParam).Hi); //error
          Windows.ScreenToClient(Handle, Point);
          Windows.GetClientRect(Handle, Rect);
          if FSizeable and (Point.x > Rect.Right - 16) and
            (Point.y > Rect.Bottom - 16) then
            Result := HTBOTTOMRIGHT
         else
            Result := HTCLIENT;
        end;
      WM_SETCURSOR:
        begin
          case LongRec(LParam).Lo of // error
            HTBOTTOMRIGHT:
              SetCursor(LoadCursor(0, IDC_SIZENWSE));
```

...

Somewhere I read that the casting LongRec(LParam) is the problem. I was wondering instead of casting LParam/WParam to LongRec.Hi/Lo, is it ok to use LoWord (for LongRec.Lo) and HiWord (for LongRec.Hi) from WinApi.Windows?

Comment: LPARAM and WPARAM are pointer sized, so can be either 32 or 64 bit. Look in the VCL source code for examples of how to handle his elegantly. I can't recall the technique off the top of my head.

Comment: As can be expected, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-nchittest) will be helpful too: *" *Important* Do not use the LOWORD or HIWORD ..."*.

Comment: IMO the cleanest is to use the provided twmnchittest structure which has a Pos field.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use Low And High functions, it will consider 32 or 64

```
Point.X := Low(LParam);
Point.Y := High(LParam);
```